# set dropdown value by text using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown as:

```
<select id="HowYouKnow" >
  <option value="1">FRIEND</option>
  <option value="2">GOOGLE</option>
  <option value="3">AGENT</option></select>
```

In the above dropdown i know the text of the dropdown. How can set the value of the dropdown in document.ready with the text using jquery?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

This is a method that works based on the **text** of the option, not the index.  Just tested.

```
var theText = "GOOGLE";
$("#HowYouKnow option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Or, if there are similar values (thanks shanabus):

```
$("#HowYouKnow option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == theText) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

Comment: This does not work in the case where your `select` list contains `options` with similar text values, ie `<option>GOOGLE</option><option>GOOGLE PLUS</option>` - thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: To handle the similar values prolem you can get the first match with the index [0] (the default returns the last index) like this: $("#HowYouKnow option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected')[0];

Comment: The above methods are broken in jquery from version 1.9.1 and newer. Change .attr to .prop -> test here: http://jsfiddle.net/RB5wU/579/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.  .attr isn't deprecated yet.

Comment: If it isn't multiple select, break each loop with return false from anonymous function.

Comment: It should be noted that, if possible, you should create the markup so that the *values* of your options match up with what you're trying to set. Then you can set the value of the select with jQuery. If your options used values that you knew, such as: `<option value='goog'>Google<option>`, you could simply do this: `$("#HowYouKnow").val('goog');`

*(And yes, I understand that this is not what the OP asked – we can't always change the markup – but it might prove useful for someone trying to understand this)*

Answer (score 17):

For the exact match use

```
    $("#HowYouKnow option").filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "GOOGLE"; }).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

contains is going to select the last match which might not be exact.

Comment: In my case `.attr()` did changed `selected` option in dom but text displayed did not changed, `.prop()` on other hand would do both things at a time.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#HowYouKnow option[value='" + theText + "']").attr('selected', 'selected'); // added single quotes
```

Comment: Think this only works with the index not the text.

Answer (score 4):

try this..

```
$(element).find("option:contains(" + theText+ ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myText = 'GOOGLE';

$('#HowYouKnow option').map(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == myText) return this;
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

For GOOGLE, GOOGLEDOWN, GOOGLEUP i.e similar kind of value you can try below code

```
   $("#HowYouKnow option:contains('GOOGLE')").each(function () {

                        if($(this).html()=='GOOGLE'){
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                    });
```

In this way,number of  loop iteration can be reduced and will work in all situation.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me -:

```
jQuery('[id^=select_] > option').each(function(){
        if (this.text.toLowerCase()=='text'){
            jQuery('[id^=select_]').val(this.value);
        }
});
```

**jQuery('[id^=select_]')** - This allows you to select drop down where ID of the drop down starts from **select_**

Hope the above helps!

Cheers
S

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example:

```
$("#country_id").change(function(){
    if(this.value.toString() == ""){
        return;
    }
    alert("You just changed country to: " + $("#country_id option:selected").text() + " which carried the value for country_id as: " + this.value.toString());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#HowYouKnow").val("GOOGLE");
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#HowYouKnow").val("GOOGLE");
        });

Sets the value too... not sure why I got down voted!

Comment: Maybe because that only works if your `option` value is the same as the text.  So in the OP's example, the GOOGLE text option has a value of `2` so it does not work.

Comment: This will only set based on the value box, not based on the dropdowns text.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#HowYouKnow option:eq(XXX)").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

where XXX is the index of the one you want.

Comment: How can i get the index of the text?

Comment: See my answer...tested and working.

Comment: the question is set dropdown value by text, not by index.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to set the selection based on the text, not the index.

Answer (score -1):

This is worked both chrome and firefox

set value in to dropdown box.

```
var given = $("#anotherbox").val();
$("#HowYouKnow").text(given).attr('value', given);
```

Comment: Don't think so... 
$("#HowYouKnow").text(.....) will remove all the options